# Recieving Highchart error 15 only in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highcharts

Alright so I have my code working in Firefox and IE just fine but whenever I load the page in Chrome the graphs come out all wonky and I get an error #15 saying that I need to resort my data in order but as far as I can tell it is. Especially since it works in the other two just fine.
I'm pulling out of a csv file so my data looks like [date],[data],[data] or 13-Jun,2345,6789. I thought that maybe I needed to do it so that my date was set up as Jun-13,2345,6789 but that doesn't seem to help either.
I'm also running the latest highcharts version as well.
Here's my code:

```
    $(function(){
var library = ['data/attendanceGroup.csv', 'data/circ.csv', 'data/class.csv', 'data/data.csv', 'data/database.csv', 'data/dcirc.csv', 'data/ebook.csv', 'data/location.csv', 'data/smedia1.csv', 'data/smedia2.csv', 'data/smedia3.csv', 'data/smedia4.csv', 'data/traffic.csv', 'data/users.csv', 'data/wtraffic.csv', 'data/children.csv', 'data/childrenA.csv'];
var area =['#attendanceGroup', '#circ', '#class', '#attendanceRoom', '#database', '#dcirc', '#ebook', '#location', '#smedia', '#smedia2', '#smedia3', '#smedia4', '#traffic', '#users', '#wtraffic', '#children', '#childrenA'];
var types = ['area', 'area', 'line', 'area', 'line', 'area', 'line', 'line', 'line', 'line', 'line', 'line', 'line', 'area', 'line', 'line', 'line'];
var texts = ['Attendance by Age Group', 'Circulation', 'Technology Classes', 'Attendance by Room', 'Non-ICONN Databases', 'Digital Circulation', 'Ebook Circulation', 'Circ by Checkout Location', 'Social Media Engagement Averages', 'Social Media Reach/Impressions Averages', 'Social Media Reach/Impressions Totals', 'Social Media Engagement Totals', 'Foot Traffic', 'Technology Users', 'Web Traffic', 'Children Programming', 'Children Programming Attendance'];
var libraryLength = library.length;
var i = 0;

function areaChart(lib, area, type, texts){
    $(function () { 
        $.get(lib, function(csv) {
            $(area).highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: type
                },
                data: {
                    csv: csv
                },
                title: {
                    text: texts
                },
                xaxis: {
                    type : 'category'
                    categories : 'data'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                    text: null
                    },
                    minorTickInterval: 'auto'
                },

                legend:{
                    align: 'left',  
                },
            });
        }); 
    });
}

for (i = 0; i < libraryLength; i++){
    areaChart(library[i], area[i], types[i], texts[i]);
}});
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you shared a working JSFiddle that we can investigate.

Comment: How your data does it look like ?